# Print json string to html table

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a very complex JSON string, which is been created by GsonBuilder (in xxx.java)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String message = gson.toJson(output);
out.println(message);
```

and it look like this:

```
{ "status": "error", "number of record loaded": [ { "bid.csv": 24 }, { "course.csv": 12 }, { "course_completed.csv": 0 }, { "prerequisites.csv": 1 }, { "section.csv": 14 }, { "student.csv": 11 } ], "errorList": [ { "file": "student.csv", "line": 9, "message": [ "duplicate userid" ] }, { "file": "student.csv", "line": 10, "message": [ "invalid e-dollar" ] }, { "file": "student.csv", "line": 11, "message": [ "invalid e-dollar" ] }, { "file": "course.csv", "line": 4, "message": [ "invalid exam start" ] }, { "file": "course.csv", "line": 10, "message": [ "invalid exam date" ] }, { "file": "course.csv", "line": 11, "message": [ "invalid exam date" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 2, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 4, "message": [ "invalid section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 7, "message": [ "invalid day" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 8, "message": [ "invalid start" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 14, "message": [ "invalid size" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 15, "message": [ "invalid size" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 18, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 19, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 20, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 21, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "section.csv", "line": 22, "message": [ "invalid course", "duplicate section" ] }, { "file": "prerequisite.csv", "line": 2, "message": [ "invalid course" ] }, { "file": "prerequisite.csv", "line": 3, "message": [ "invalid prerequisite" ] }, { "file": "course_completed.csv", "line": 2, "message": [ "invalid userid" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 2, "message": [ "invalid amount" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 3, "message": [ "invalid section" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 4, "message": [ "invalid section" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 5, "message": [ "not own school course" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 6, "message": [ "incomplete prerequisites" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 13, "message": [ "section limit reached" ] }, { "file": "bid.csv", "line": 14, "message": [ "insufficient e$" ] } ] }
```

I wish to pass this value using this code:

```
context.setAttribute("message", message);
response.sendRedirect("zzz.jsp");
```

So in zzz.jsp how am I suppose to print the above complex json string to table? It should display something like

```
LinkedHashMap map = null;
String status = null;
JSONArray jArr = null;
try {
    map = (LinkedHashMap) context.getAttribute("bootstrapStatus");     
    status = (String) map.get("status");
    out.println("<p><font color = 'red'> Bootstrap Status: " + status + "</font></p>");
    jArr = (JSONArray) map.get("num-record-loaded");

} catch (NullPointerException npe){
    status = "Error: no bootstrap";
    out.println("<p>"+status + "</p>");
}

if (map != null) {
%>
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" > 
    <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td>CSV File</td>
            <td>Number of records</td>
        <tr></tr>
        <%
            for (Object obj : jArr) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
                Set keys = jsonObj.keySet();
                Iterator iter = keys.iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    String fileName = (String) iter.next();
                    int successLine = (Integer) jsonObj.get(fileName);
                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>" + fileName + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + successLine + "</td>");
                    out.println("</tr>");
                }
            }
            %>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p><strong>Error Messages</strong></p>

        <%
            if (status.equals("error")) {
            %>

        <div class="CSSTableGenerator" > 
            <table align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td>CSV File</td>
                    <td>Line number</td>
                    <td>Error message</td>
                <tr></tr>
                <%
                        ArrayList<BootstrapError> errArr = (ArrayList<BootstrapError>) map.get("error");

                        for (BootstrapError error : errArr) {
                            out.println("<tr>");
                            out.println("<td>" + error.getFile() + "</td>");
                            out.println("<td>" + error.getLine() + "</td>");
                            out.println("<td>" + error.getMessage() + "</td>");
                            out.println("</tr>");
                        }
                    }
            }
                %>
            </table>
```

and I know theres an error with regards with this: `map = (LinkedHashMap) context.getAttribute("message");` so I changed it to:

```
String s = (String) context.getAttribute("message");
            LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();
            map.put("message",s);
            String status = (String) map.get("status"); <<< this appear null
            JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray) map.get("num-record-loaded");  <<< this appears Null
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated! (:

Comment: Would you mind to create a jsfiddle example? This would reduce the complexity of your post.

Comment: Oh, there was a mistake of mine. I thought you posted a mix of html and javascript, based on you added tags.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that `context.getAttribute("message");` is not null? It seems you don't put that into request.

Comment: I think the best way would be to set a JavaScript variable to the contents of your JSON string.  Basically, you need to get the JSON into the context of the JS on the page.  You can find JSON parsers at http://JSON.org.  I don't know why you are setting the message as JSON anyway...it doesn't seem like you are using AJAX or anything like that, so it seems like an unneeded step IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't understand the reason of packing into JSON, if all you wanted to do is use scriptlets & display it. You could have simply sent the `output` object itself through context to the redirected page.
2. I guess you have something else in mind. Talking about the question, here's how you can do it :

```
    String temp=map = (LinkedHashMap) context.getAttribute("message"); 
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement ele = jp.parse(temp);
    JsonObject obj=ele.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray jArr =Jsobj.get("number of record loaded").getAsJsonArray();
```

**Update**

The way of iterating over the JsonArray isn't correct, here's a sample on how to iterate over JsonArray :

```
                Iterator<JsonElement> msg = jsonArray.iterator();
                while (msg.hasNext()) {
                    ////prints json array values
                    JsonElement eleTemp = msg.next();
                    JsonObject jObj = eleTemp.getAsJsonObject();
                    //... Other code
                }
```

Comment: Hello, do u meant like this?

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String message = gson.toJson(output);
out.println(message);
context.setAttribute("message", output);
response.sendRedirect("BootstrapOutput.jsp");