# Java List of custom objects inside response object not populated with GSON unmarshaller

Tags: java, json, gson

Basically, I marshall on one server into JSON, then send it to another server, where it should be unmarshalled. I use a response object called list wrapper, so that if there are any errors I can pass them along. With the JSON marshalled below by badgerfish(jettison), in a resteasy class, then returned to the other server,  GSON will unmarshall to a listwrapper object, but the list inside is null. Any ideas?
Note: The list must remain generic because different objects may go into the list, though the list will always only have one type in it at a time.

Json

unmarshalling

```
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();    
        Gson gson = builder.create(); 
        Object List;
        if (!JSON.equals("")) {
            List = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(JSON)), ListWrapper.class);
        }
```

Listwrapper type

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListWrapper")

public class ListWrapper {

    private Vector<Object> objects;
    private String status;
    private int batch;

    private ValidationException e;

    public ListWrapper() {
        this.setStatus("Success");
    }

    public ListWrapper(Vector<Object> list) {
        this.setStatus("Success");
        this.objects = list;
    }

    public ListWrapper(int x) {
        this.setStatus("batch");
        this.batch = x;
    }

    public Vector<Object> getList() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setList(Vector<Object> object) {
        this.objects = object;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ThrowableAdapter.class)
    public ValidationException getE() {
        if (e != null) {
            return e;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setE(ValidationException x) {
        this.e = x;
    }

    public int getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(int batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deserialize using directly `ListWrapper`, you need a container class, this is why you list is empty. By the way, your list is not a list but a map instead (curly braces limit content of `list`).

I created a code that correctly parse your JSON and provides you with some simple functionality to extract data. Since you want to keep flexible the data you are passing between the servers, you will need strings to access to data.

Here is the code ready to copy and paste to try it by yourself. Keep in mind that accessor methods are based on structure you are showing in the example. I provided you in main 4 different kind of data you can extract from it. Let me know if you need more information about that.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19817221;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q19817221 {

    public class ListWrapper {

        private Map list;
        private Map status;
        private Map batch;

        private Object extractValue(Map m) {
            return m.get("$");
        }

        public Integer getBatch() {
            return Integer.valueOf( (String) extractValue(batch));
        }

        public Object getValueFromList(String key) {
            try {
                Map m = (Map) list.get(key);
                if (m != null)
                    return extractValue(m);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return list.get(key);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Object getValueFromList(String secondLevelKey, String key) {

            Map secondLevelMap = (Map) list.get(secondLevelKey);
            try {
                Map m = (Map) secondLevelMap.get(key);
                if (m != null)
                    return extractValue(m);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return list.get(key);
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

    public class Container {
        public ListWrapper ListWrapper;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String json = "{\"ListWrapper\":{\"batch\":{\"$\":\"0\"},\"list\":{\"@xmlns\":{\"xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"},\"@xsi:type\":\"fidsUsers\",\"createdBy\":{\"$\":\"administrator\"},\"createdWhen\":{\"$\":\"2013-02-25T17:29:19-05:00\"},\"endDate\":{\"$\":\"2016-10-28T00:00:00-04:00\"}," +
            "\"isDisabled\":{\"$\":\"N\"},\"previousPasswords\":{\"$\":\"HXQDa4WxTdBmZtvhMVTgnw==@@@@zW6bdHkKdMN2p6CgRNjNHA==@@@@Sim7JN3kaHoXnh3KUS2++Q==@@@@Emz7zU0Wrm0lyb/K522O5A==@@ZirxzRl28JqfjOzIaMzAog==\"}," +
            "\"primaryKey\":{\"$\":\"David\"},\"pswdChgDate\":{\"$\":\"2013-07-12T08:27:46-04:00\"},\"pswdCount\":{\"$\":\"0\"},\"roleId\":{\"$\":\"Admin\"},\"roleIdFidsRoles\":{\"globalAccess\":{\"$\":\"Y\"},\"primaryKey\":{\"$\":\"Admin\"},\"roleDesc\":{\"$\":\"Administrator\"},\"roleId\":{\"$\":\"Admin\"}," +
            "\"updatedBy\":{\"$\":\"David\"}},\"startDate\":{\"$\":\"1992-07-28T00:00:00-04:00\"},\"updatedBy\":{\"$\":\"David\"},\"updatedWhen\":{\"$\":\"2013-10-02T10:46:31-04:00\"},\"userId\":{\"$\":\"David\"},\"userName\":{\"$\":\"David3\"},\"userPassword\":{\"$\":\"HXQDa4WxTdBmZtvhMVTgnw==\"}},\"status\":{\"$\":\"Success\"}}}";


       Container c = new Gson().fromJson(json, Container.class);
       ListWrapper lw = c.ListWrapper;

       System.out.println("batch:" + lw.getBatch());
       System.out.println("createdBy:" + lw.getValueFromList("createdBy"));
       System.out.println("@xsi:type: " + lw.getValueFromList("@xsi:type"));

       System.out.println("roleIdFidsRoles\\primaryKey: " + lw.getValueFromList("roleIdFidsRoles", "primaryKey"));



    }
}
```

This is execution result:

```
batch:0
createdBy:administrator
@xsi:type: fidsUsers
roleIdFidsRoles\primaryKey: Admin
```

Comment: But if I have different objects in the list, now it becomes difficult to use strings to find it. You said that the list I have has actually be come a map when it was serialized. I'm using badgerfish(jettison) on a RestEasy service to make the json from JAXB xml. Do you think if I created the JSON just with GSON it would serialize correctly down to a list, so that I could deserialize it correctly?

Comment: I really do not know badgefish, so my comment will be limited to what I know: Gson. If you have the same technology on both servers (Java I mean), you can serialize with Gson from one side and deserialize with Gson again on the other. If both servers have a jar containing your classes is quite simple to do. If you are in this case, I suggest you to use Gson only. About this question, Gson produces a map since a map is what is serialized in the Json string. Copy and paste your JSON into http://json.parser.online.fr/ for example to "navigate" it.

Comment: About your current question, you asked how to deserialize and this is, to my knowledge, the best option you have. Of course is not an object easy to handle, once you got it. So, again, if you can code both side of the servers, use Gson to serialize and deserialize passing your classes.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into your `ListWrapper` class and a `json` you have posted - you have a mismatch and that is probably why it failed to unmarshall.

For:
`{"ListWrapper":{"batch":{"$":"0"},"list":{"@xmlns":{"xsi":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance"},"@xsi:type":"fidsUsers","createdBy":{"$":"administrator"},"createdWhen":{"$":"2013-02-25T17:29:19-05:00"},"endDate":{"$":"2016-10-28T00:00:00-04:00"},"isDisabled":{"$":"N"},"previousPasswords":{"$":"HXQDa4WxTdBmZtvhMVTgnw==@@@@zW6bdHkKdMN2p6CgRNjNHA==@@@@Sim7JN3kaHoXnh3KUS2++Q==@@@@Emz7zU0Wrm0lyb\/K522O5A==@@ZirxzRl28JqfjOzIaMzAog=="},"primaryKey":{"$":"David"},"pswdChgDate":{"$":"2013-07-12T08:27:46-04:00"},"pswdCount":{"$":"0"},"roleId":{"$":"Admin"},"roleIdFidsRoles":{"globalAccess":{"$":"Y"},"primaryKey":{"$":"Admin"},"roleDesc":{"$":"Administrator"},"roleId":{"$":"Admin"},"updatedBy":{"$":"David"}},"startDate":{"$":"1992-07-28T00:00:00-04:00"},"updatedBy":{"$":"David"},"updatedWhen":{"$":"2013-10-02T10:46:31-04:00"},"userId":{"$":"David"},"userName":{"$":"David3"},"userPassword":{"$":"HXQDa4WxTdBmZtvhMVTgnw=="}},"status":{"$":"Success"}}}` to me it is a `object ListWrapper` that has 3 fields named: batch, list and status, where batch is an object with one field being a number, list is a map and status is an object having one string in it.

I am not familiar with badgerfish, having said that, in your `ListWrapper` try to change `private Vector<Object> objects` to `private Map<String,Object> objects` (and of course matching getters/setters) and see if that will work

Comment: The problem with making it a map, is that it's not a map. I have objects I'm passing in with no key. For me to create a map, I would need to provide keys(strings) for each object that I send to between the servers.

Answer (score 1):

> The list must remain generic because different objects may go into
>   the list, though the list will always only have one type in it at a
>   time.

If you know what type is it before un-marshalling, then ONLY it can work through the use of [TypeToken](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

Sample code :

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(foo, fooType);

gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Also, the definition will change to something like this :

```
    public class ListWrapper {

        private Vector<T> objects;
        private String status;
        private int batch;
}
```

or

```
public class ListWrapper {

    private Vector<T extends someBaseObject> objects;
    private String status;
    private int batch;
}
```

depends on how exactly you decide to implement.

Comment: How would this work for a list nested inside the object I'm unmarshalling? I saw type tokens, and it seems like what I want, but I don't see how you can do it with this case because the list is inside another object, so if I unmarshall that outer object with the type token for the list it won't work.

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808462/print-json-string-to-html-table/19821819#19821819). You can extract out the inner list and then use TypeTokens to parse it.